# how to display a array element one by one with a spacebar in a input field in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a large array with a lot of string
i want to display it in a text field one by one with a space bar concatenate to each one automatically

my code here

```
<script>
    x=0
    function abc(){

    for (i=0;i<words[x].length;i++){
        if(x=0)
            x++;

        document.getElementById("type").value=words[x];
    }

</script>
```

my input field id is `type` and my array is `words`

Answer (score 4):

Each iteration sets the value to a new word, it does'nt add to the value. You could just join the array with a space and set it as the elements value :

```
document.getElementById("type").value = words.join(' ');
```